# Open URI downloading corrupt files

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am trying to download a .tar.gz file using Ruby. Upon download, the file is always corrupt in some way.

I am using this code to download the file:

```
require "open-uri"
File.open('img.tar.gz', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open('https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/blob/master/img.tar.gz').read 
end
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't made myself clearer. But I wanted to download zip files using ruby and for some reason the file gets corrupted. So I wanted to ask if there another ways to do it ?

Comment: In what way is the file "corrupted"? Have you examined the file to see what data actually gets downloaded?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to say this. But If i Try to open the file it says error occured while loading the archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file mode in the `open` call:

```
open('https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/blob/master/img.tar.gz', "rb").read
```

It was opening the file in *text* mode, when you wanted *binary* mode.

You also needed to be using the proper URL to download a raw file from Github.  In this case, the correct URL can be found by right-clicking the `Raw` link on the file's repo page (the original URL given), and that `Raw` URL is the one that contains the actual binary image that you're trying to download.  Change the URL to this: https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/raw/master/img.tar.gz, and the change I suggested at the top of the answer works just fine.

Comment: a.rb:3:in `write': not opened for writing (IOError)    
   from a.rb:3:in `block in <main>'    
 from a.rb:2:in `open'    
 from a.rb:2:in `<main>'

Comment: Thanks but its still not working. The link is public and you can try downloading too. Is it working for you ?

Comment: @ArafatK using `curl -g https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/blob/master/img.tar.gz -o img.tar.gz` results in the same corrupted file.  Github (the file's host) is returning HTML instead of a .tar.gz file.  `cat img.tar.gz` shows an HTML page, not a binary bytes, as you would expect from a .tar.gz file.

Comment: This is the actual file that you wanted to download: [https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/raw/master/img.tar.gz](https://github.com/Arafatk/language-basics/raw/master/img.tar.gz)

Comment: Note that github has a button labeled `Raw` on the page that's used to get the URL that I just gave you.  Otherwise, you get the HTML page that displays information about your file in the repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Basically what I am trying to do is that I want to upload a zip file online anywhere and then download and extract it and perform some image processing operations on it. I am done with the rest of the thing when i tried them locally but I cannot download the zip file ? Can you recommend a way to upload a zip file anywhere and then download it ?

Comment: Technically, that's a different question.  It depends on where you want to upload it.  If you open another question, you'll be able to get an answer for that.

Comment: I am okay with any website where i could make it public.

Comment: You have Dropbox, Box.net, Amazon S3, and a host of others.  Your ISP probably has an open file share.  You'll need to pick one and then open a new question to find out the specific details.  Asking a question like "to which website can I upload a file?" will probably get closed immediately.  Ask something like "How do I use Ruby to write a file to host X", once you decide what `host X` will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: My pleasure.  Good luck, and I'll watch out for the next question.